# python html parser not returning link

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have been trying to parse rss news feed and I managed to get most fields but the link to the article and the publication date. 
This is my code:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
#import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rss_url="https://news.google.com/news/rss/search/section/q/australia/australia?hl=en-AU&gl=AU&ned=au"
Client=urlopen(rss_url)
xml_page=Client.read()
Client.close()
soup_page=soup(xml_page,"html.parser")
#soup_page=ET.parse(xml_page)
news_list=soup_page.findAll("item")
# Print news title, url and publish date
for news in news_list:
  #text=news.text
  title=news.title.text
  link=news.link.text
  pubdate=news.pubDate.text
  description=news.description.text
  publisher = re.findall('<font color="#6f6f6f">(.*?)</font>', description)
  article_link=link
  article_info=[title,publisher,link,pubdate]
  print(article_info)
```

I got most fields but pubdate and link. Any idea what could help? Many thanks!

Comment: What do you get for pubdate and link?  Are they blank?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I got blank returned, no error.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `pubDate` and `link` fields:

The `pubDate` field can be retrieved by using all lower case:

```
pubdate=news.pubdate.text
```

The `link` field is captured correctly with the previous version of Beautiful Soup, 4.5.3, but not in the current version 4.6.0. 4.6.0 results in the blank line you are seeing. Install 4.5.3 with the following:

```
$ pip3 uninstall beautifulsoup4
$ pip3 install 'beautifulsoup4==4.5.3'
```

Here's the Beautiful Soup release history. 4.5.3 was released on Jan 2, 2017 and 4.6.0 was released on May 7, 2017.

- https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/#history

I'm using Python 3.6.0 on macOS.

Here are the first two lines with the update showing all the fields.

`['Coalition party room split over national energy guarantee – politics live', ['The Guardian'], 'https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/live/2018/may/29/nationals-barnaby-joyce-superannuation-coalition-banking-royal-commission-tax-politics-live', 'Mon, 28 May 2018 22:37:07 GMT']`

`['Residential rental agreements in Australia falling behind rest of the world: tenants union', ['ABC Online'], 'http://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-05-29/residential-rental-agreements-in-australia-need-updating/9809364', 'Mon, 28 May 2018 19:39:43 GMT']`

Comment: Thanks for the pubdate tip! That works now. But link still doesn't work for me. It still returns blank ...

Comment: There is a problem with Beautiful Soup 4.6.0. Downgrading to 4.5.3 works. I've updated the answer with the `pip3` commands to uninstall 4.6.0 and install 4.5.3.

Comment: I tried installing the 4.5.3 version with pip but it keep saying that that it's an invalid requirement ...

Comment: Even the soup ver 4.5.3 doesn't help with the link problem.

Comment: What version of Python and what OS/version are you using? I'm using Python 3.6.0 on macOS.

Comment: I am using Python 3.4 and Microsoft Windows 7.